# Forward internet and use as Gateway

Tags: networking, routing, ethernet, nat, bridge

Windows Server 2019.

Fairly simple (I guess). I have two ethernet adaptors, one has internet and the other don't. The second will be on the same network as another computer and this computer need to use internet!

Subnet1 (has internet)
IP: 172.24.x.y (same network as Gw)
Mask: 255.255.240.0
Gw: 172.24.112.1

Subnet2
IP: 192.168.0.1
Mask: 255.255.255.0
Gw:

Machine
IP: 192.168.0.2
Mask: 255.255.255.0
Gw: 192.168.0.1

Can it be solved?

Answer (score 0):

A Pc can be part of more than one network.

1. Open **Network and Sharing Center**
2. Select **Connection** from the right of the divider.  If there is more than, you have to find the correct one.
3. Click on **Properties** Button
4. Select **Internet Protocol Version 4**
5. Click on **Properties** Button
6. Click on **Advanced** Button
7. On the top pane, click on **Add** button
8. Enter the IP address and subnet.